# Might I need to change my PC's god to move to another AL table?

Tags: dnd-5e, religions-and-deities, dnd-adventurers-league

I'm entering Tier 2 in Adventurers League, and when I do I'll be switching to a different, already established group and DM. The one that fits my schedule best with openings at the table is also using a different adventure (Storm King's Thunder).

I haven't switched groups yet, and I'm going over my character now to try to anticipate issues. I don't know what problems might arise or what rules there are on the subject. The things I'm not sure about are *equipment*, *alignment*, *Background*, and **deity**.

The first three are solved, so it's just the last I'm not sure about. I already confirmed other aspects of my character are okay: The old DM instructed me with what to do about my equipment, I don't have any issues with alignment to worry about. So I'm just trying to figure out if keeping my current **deity** is normal, or if there's any reason I might have to change it to fit my PC into the new table's party.

Are there any rules about gods that might be relevant to switching tables, or roleplay issues with choice of gods, or something about the adventure, that would mean I might want to change my PC's choice?

Comment: @JohnathanGross [Please don't answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) We have zero acceptance of doing so & I have removed that comment per standard procedure. If the question is on hold, *still* do not answer in comments. Use comments for their intended purpose to work to get the question reopened if that's possible. If it isn't, well, c'est la vie -- we're fine without that comment being posted at all. You could work it into a self-answered Q&A if that's a desirable way to share that knowledge.

Comment: @doppelgreener Ok, well the question has a non-opinion based answer, removing the reason for the hold and I don't believe it needs to be edited to be correctly answered, so all I can do right now is say I believe it should be reopened.

Comment: Based on a [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62888), I've come to the tentative conclusion that being closed as Primarily Opinion-Based *might* have been due to the question being unclear and voters misunderstanding it as a request for opinions. (That said, we tend to still not mod-unhold when another hold reason still applies, such as maybe being Unclear.) Based on that chat I gave this an extensive edit. I'm not sure if the edit succeeds in solving hold voters' issues, so I'll let the voters determine if it's sufficiently improved or not. Cheers everyone!

Comment: Why do you think you cannot keep your deity? Is it incompatible with the setting or the party composition of the new game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from Clerics, choice of deity is a purely role-play character element and it isn't an issue to choose a different one. If you're a cleric, however, then your deity could influence your selection of a domain and since you're into tier 2, you're 5th level or higher and, as the AL Player's Guide states, ineligible for a rebuild. Since any cleric can choose Life as a domain, if that was your selected domain, then a change in deity wouldn't necessarily alter that choice, so you could do it as long as you kept the Life domain.

Changing your characters deity could be a cool RP element to add to your character, why did they change deities? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

According to page 3 of the [Adventurers League Player's Guide](http://dndadventurersleague.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/DDAL-PLAYERS-GUIDE-v.6.0.pdf)

> Whether your character is a cleric or not, if they worship a deity, you may choose only from those deities listed in the **Deities of the Forgotten Realms** and **Nonhuman Deities** tables in the Player’s Handbook or any of the deities listed in any of the resources listed in Step 1& 2, above. Note, however, if the deity doesn’t include suggested domains in the resource in which it is found, only the Life domain is available.

The "resources listed in Step 1& 2" are

> • Elemental Evil Player’s Companion
>   • Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide
>   • Volo’s Guide to Monsters

EE doesn't introduce any deities. Volo's introduces a number of dieties, but most of them are evil. SCAG introduces a large number of deities.

So if your deity was Adventurers League compliant before switching tables, it should still be compliant now. Since AL occurs in relatively the same universe no matter what table you play at, it shouldn't cause any problems. Everything else is a discussion you should have with your DM.